# Подскажите аналог плагина emmet для редактора atom

Tags: sublime-text, atom, emmet

Подскажите аналог плагина emmet как в sublime но для редактора atom.

Comment: так и называется в atom тоже emmet - разве в поиске плагинов не выдаёт результата ?

Comment: Нет такого, может версия другая?

Comment: вопрос удалите - минусов навтыкают

Comment: он вообще тяжёлый и я им не пользуюсь ... хоть и x64 у меня но мне он не подходит ... хотя раньше только в нём дела делал ...и точно есть emmet

Comment: А у вас какой проц? Я как раз собираюсь комп менять

Comment: https://atom.io/packages/emmet
https://atom.io/packages/emmet-simplified

Comment: i7 у меня и 16 Ггб памяти - у меня Линуксовые проги быстрее включаются чем Atom

Comment: А у меня щас старый core2duo и включается за 5с

Comment: [вот скриншот](https://www.dropbox.com/s/po2ubc792jzrsq8/2019-01-11_113003.png) завёлся у меня atom